# Sulu CMF - Filtered Single autocomplete selection for associated entity

Tags: reactjs, symfony, fosrestbundle, sulu

I have two entities:

```php
class DataSet {
  string $name;
  Collection $groups; // List<DataGroup>
}
class DataGroup {
  string $name;
  DataSet $set;
  DataGroup $nextGroup;
}
```

I created some basic Admin UI extensions for CRUD operations on `DataSet`s, as per [docs](https://docs.sulu.io/en/latest/book/extend-admin.html). Now I also want to perform CRUD operations on the associated `DataGroup`s of a `DataSet`. For that, I first looked at the [ContactBundle Javascript extension](https://github.com/sulu/sulu/blob/2.x/src/Sulu/Bundle/ContactBundle/Resources/js/index.js) and registered a `CardCollection` for the `$groups` field, which came with an overlay form (providing a form schema, etc).

`DataGroup::nextGroup` is supposed to be any *other* `DataGroup` entity sharing the same `DataSet`. How can I provide all matching entities to the component in a `SingleAutoComplete`?

**UPDATE 2021-09-09**

I switched to the intended approach of configuration-wise implementation.

I also made a [followup question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69120159/sulu-cmf-pass-parameter-to-autocomplete-field-in-formoverlaylist-add-form) to narrow down my exact problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer to this question is very similar to your other question ([Sulu CMF - CRUD Filtered Multi-Item-Selection for association entities](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68943054/16151545)). It sounds like you want to implement a selection for the `DataGroup` entity. As already included in the [answer to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68951117/16151545), the [Sulu Workshop](https://github.com/sulu/sulu-workshop/pull/16) and the [Sulu Demo](https://github.com/sulu/sulu-demo/pull/85) both contain a code example how to do this.

You can check all available configuration options for you selection field-type by printing the configuration reference for the `SuluAdminBundle` with the following command:

```sh
bin/console config:dump-reference sulu_admin
```

Sulu uses the same mechanism for registering selection field-types for built-in entities like the [`contact_selection`](https://docs.sulu.io/en/2.3/reference/content-types/contact_selection.html) or the [`single_account_selection`](https://docs.sulu.io/en/2.3/reference/content-types/single_account_selection.html). This means that your custom selection field-type supports the same parameters that are supported by the built-in field types and [can be found in the Sulu documentation](https://docs.sulu.io/en/2.3/reference/content-types/contact_selection.html).

For example, if you want to add a parameter that is sent to the server when loading the selectable items, you can use the `request_parameters` param or the `resource_store_properties_to_request` param in your form configuration. An example for this could look like this:

```xml
<property name="custom_selection" type="custom_selection">
    <params>
        <param name="request_parameters" type="collection">
            <param name="static-parameter" value="static-value" />
        </param>
        <param name="resource_store_properties_to_request" type="collection">
            <param name="dynamic-parameter" value="other-property-name" />
        </param>
    </params>
</property>
```

This selection field-type will use the [list route of the configured resource key](https://docs.sulu.io/en/2.3/book/extend-admin.html#configure-resources) to load the selectable items. To actually filter the selectable items, you need to handle the parameter that is sent by the selection field-type in the controller of the list route. If you use the Sulu `ListBuilder` service in this controller, the filtering could look something like this:

```php
$filterValue = $request->query->get('static-parameter');
$listBuilder->where($fieldDescriptors['filtered-property-name'], $filterValue);
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip on the configuration options. However, as of [my comment to the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68943054/sulu-cmf-crud-multi-item-selection-for-association-entities/68951117#121919962), I fail to see a possibility to implement additional respository filters for these approaches. Is there a way?

Comment: Yes, you can use the `request_parameters` param or `resource_store_properties_to_request` param to add a parameter to the request that loads the selectable items. I have added an example for this to my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the example. I've gained significant insight from your explanations and updated my question with my current approach. Both `data_groups.xml` and the `data_group.xml` form are now within a `FormOverlayList` in a separate tab, and rendering is fine - however, when trying to add a new `DataGroup`, I fail to pass `DataSet.id` into the `nextGroup` property, and the Route declines the list route request - did I use `resource_store_properties_to_request` correct?

Comment: I am sorry, I do not understand what you are trying to do. I think it would be helpful to create a new question that includes screenshots, a description of the desired behaviour and your existing code (including the code of your controller).

Comment: I see. I'll link you the question.

Comment: I posted the new question with all pieces of sourcecode relevant to my remaining problem. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69120159/sulu-cmf-pass-parameter-to-autocomplete-field-in-formoverlaylist-add-form).