# Sulu CMF - CRUD Filtered Multi-Item-Selection for association entities

Tags: reactjs, symfony, fosrestbundle, sulu

I have three entities:

```php
class DataSet {
  string $name;
  Collection $points; // List<DataPoint>
  Collection $groups; // List<DataGroup>
}
class DataGroup {
  string $name;
  Collection $assignedPoints; // List<DataGroupPoint>
}
class DataPoint {
  string $name;
  Collection $assignedGroups; // List<DataGroupPoint>
}
class DataGroupPoint {
  DataGroup $group;
  DataPoint $point;
  int $data;
}
```

I extended the Admin UI to perform CRUD operations on the `DataSet` entity, as per [docs](https://docs.sulu.io/en/latest/book/extend-admin.html). By looking at the [ContactBundle Javascript extension](https://github.com/sulu/sulu/blob/2.x/src/Sulu/Bundle/ContactBundle/Resources/js/index.js), I was able to add CRUD operations for `DataPoint` entities within the `DataSet` form by registering a `CardCollection` - works fine.

Now, I want to perform CRUD operations on associated `DataGroup` entities of the `DataSet` as well - for that I want to put a `MultiItemSelection` component into the `DataGroup` overlay form in order to add, edit or remove `DataGroupPoint`s.

For a `DataGroupPoint` entity, both the `DataGroup` and the `DataPoint` are supposed to belong to the same `DataSet` (which in turn is being edited in the overall form).

How can I provide all matching `DataPoint` entities to the `MultiItemSelection`?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question, you are looking for a custom `data_point_selection` content type.

To achieve this I can recommend you to take a look at the Sulu Workshop, especially [assignment 11](https://github.com/sulu/sulu-workshop/pull/16). In this assignment a `single_location_selection` is implemented. This is a selection for the custom entity `location`.

Another great example for a custom `selection` or `single_selection` is the [example pull request of the sulu demo](https://github.com/sulu/sulu-demo/pull/85).

As a side note, the implementation of the `ContactBundle` is very specific for this case. Therefore the extendability and usability of the used components like `CardCollection` is not the best. For a better developer experience I would recommend you to stick to the [documented content types in the docs](https://docs.sulu.io/en/2.3/reference/content-types/index.html). Unless you really need these specific components.

Comment: When looking at both the assignment changes and the pull request, I gained an understanding on how to implement these fields, however I don't understand how to apply additional repository filters.