# Sulu CMF - Pass parameter to autocomplete field in FormOverlayList add form

Tags: php, reactjs, symfony5, sulu

This question is a [followup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68942823/sulu-cmf-filtered-single-autocomplete-selection-for-associated-entity).

I have two entities `DataSet` and `DataGroup`.

```php
class DataSet {
  string $name;
  Collection $groups; // Collection<int, DataGroup>
}
class DataGroup {
  string $name;
  DataSet $dataSet;
  ?DataGroup $nextGroup; // Condition: $nextGroup !== $this && $nextGroup->dataSet === $this->dataSet
}
```

**The property `DataGroup::nextGroup` may refer to any *other* `DataGroup` entity associated with the same `DataSet`.**

I want to create a CRUD form where I can add, edit and remove `DataSet` entities. In this `DataSet` form, I also want to include a tab where I can CRUD `DataGroup` entities associated with the current `DataSet`.

I have created list metadata `data_sets.xml` and `data_groups.xml`, as well as form metadata `data_set.xml` and `data_group.xml`.

```xml
<!-- lists/data_sets.xml -->
<list xmlns="http://schemas.sulu.io/list-builder/list">
  <key>data_sets</key>
  <properties>
    <property name="name" visibility="always" searchability="yes">
      <field-name>name</field-name>
      <entity-name>App\Entity\DataSet</entity-name>
    </property>
  </properties>
</list>

<!-- lists/data_groups.xml -->
<list xmlns="http://schemas.sulu.io/list-builder/list">
  <key>data_groups</key>
  <properties>
    <property name="name" visibility="always" searchability="yes">
      <field-name>name</field-name>
      <entity-name>App\Entity\DataSet</entity-name>
    </property>
    <property name="dataSet" visibility="always">
      <field-name>name</field-name>
      <entity-name>App\Entity\DataSet</entity-name>
      <joins>
        <join>
          <entity-name>App\Entity\DataSet</entity-name>
          <field-name>App\Entity\DataGroup.dataSet</field-name>
        </join>
      </joins>
    </property>
  </properties>
</list>
```

```xml
<!-- forms/data_set.xml -->
<form xmlns="http://schemas.sulu.io/template/template"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.sulu.io/template/template 
      http://schemas.sulu.io/template/form-1.0.xsd"
>
  <key>data_set</key>
  <properties>
    <property name="name" type="text_line" mandatory="true">
      <params>
        <param name="headline" value="true"/>
      </params>
    </property>
  </properties>
</form>

<!-- forms/data_group.xml -->
<form xmlns="http://schemas.sulu.io/template/template"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.sulu.io/template/template 
      http://schemas.sulu.io/template/form-1.0.xsd"
>
  <key>data_group</key>
  <properties>
    <property name="name" type="text_line" mandatory="true">
      <params>
        <param name="headline" value="true"/>
      </params>
    </property>
    <property name="nextGroup" type="single_data_group_selection">
      <params>
        <param name="type" value="auto_complete"/>
        <param name="resource_store_properties_to_request" type="collection">
          <param name="dataSetId" value="id"/>
        </param>
      </params>
    </property>
  </properties>
</form>
```

I have also configured `sulu_admin.yaml` for REST routes and the custom single selection:

```yaml
sulu_admin:
  resources:
    data_sets:
      routes:
        list: app.get_data_sets
        detail: app.get_data_set
    data_groups:
      routes:
        list: app.get_data_groups
        details: app.get_data_group
  field_type_options:
    single_selection:
      single_data_group_selection:
        default_type: 'auto_complete'
        resource_key: 'data_groups'
        types:
          auto_complete:
            display_property: 'name'
            search_properties:
              - 'name'
```

I implemented two REST controllers for both entities. `DataSetController` is built as of the [Docs](https://docs.sulu.io/en/2.3/book/extend-admin.html), while `DataGroupController` has a small extension for the list route:

```php
class DataGroupController implements ClassResourceInterface
{
  public function cgetAction(int $dataSetId, Request $request): Response
  {
    // ... Init field descriptors and execute listBuilder
    
    $list = new ListRepresentation(
      $listResponse,
      'data_groups',
      \array_merge(['dataSetId' => $dataSetId], $request->query->all()), // add DataSet ID
      $listBuilder->getCurrentPage(),
      $listBuilder->getLimit(),
      $listBuilder->count()
    );

    // ... handle view
  }

  // ...
}
```

Finally, I implemented a custom Admin class like explained in the [Docs](https://docs.sulu.io/en/2.3/book/extend-admin.html).

```php
class DataAdmin extends Admin
{
  public const DATA_SET_DETAILS = 'data_set_details';
  public const DATA_SET_GROUPS = 'data_set_groups';
  public const DATA_SET_LIST = 'app.data_sets_list';
  public const DATA_SET_ADD_FORM = 'app.data_set_add_form';
  public const DATA_SET_ADD_FORM_DETAILS = 'app.data_set_add_form.details';
  public const DATA_SET_EDIT_FORM = 'app.data_set_edit_form';
  public const DATA_SET_EDIT_FORM_DETAILS = 'app.data_set_edit_form.details';
  public const DATA_SET_EDIT_FORM_GROUPS = 'app.data_set_edit_form.groups';

  public function configureViews(ViewCollection $viewCollection): void
  {
    // Add DataSet list view
    // Add DataSet add form view
    // Add DataSet edit form view (details)
    
    /*
     * Custom second DataSet edit form tab for DataGroup CRUDding
     */
    $groupsFormOverlayList = $this->viewBuilderFactory
      ->createFormOverlayListViewBuilder(self::DATA_SET_EDIT_FORM_GROUPS, '/groups')
      ->setResourceKey(self::DATA_SET_GROUPS)
      ->setListKey(self::DATA_SET_GROUPS)
      ->addListAdapters(['table'])
      ->addRouterAttributesToListRequest(['id' => 'dataSetId'])
      ->setFormKey(self::DATA_SET_GROUPS)
      ->addRouterAttributesToFormRequest(['id' => 'dataSetId'])
      ->setTabTitle('app.data_groups')
      ->addToolbarActions([
        new ToolbarAction('sulu_admin.add'),
        new ToolbarAction('sulu_admin.delete')
      ])
    ;
    $viewCollection->add($groupsFormOverlayList->setParent(self::DATA_SET_EDIT_FORM));
  }
}
```

As of now

- I can perform all CRUD operations on `DataSet` entities.
- I can list and remove `DataGroup` entities belonging to a `DataSet`.

When trying to add a new `DataGroup`, I can't perform autocomplete search for `nextGroup` because the `dataSetId` parameter is **not** passed to the field, forbidding the `ResourceRequester` to perform the REST request.

**How do I pass `dataSetId` to fields of the "New `DataGroup`" form in order to search for matching entities only?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks a lot for the detailed description! Unfortunately, I am afraid that it is not possible to implement what you are trying to do while using the built-in autocomplete component at the moment.

The `resource_store_properties_to_request` param reads the values from the data of the form that renders the autocomplete component. If you are creating a new `DataGroup` entity, the data of the form is empty (because there is now existing data for a new entity) and therefore the `resource_store_properties_to_request` param is not able to read a `dataSetId` value.

I am sorry to say, but I think you would need to implement a custom autocomplete field-type that reads the `dataSetId` value from the current url to achieve the desired functionality. If you are interested in doing this, I would recommend to have a look at the [basic field-type example in the sulu-demo repository](https://github.com/sulu/sulu-demo/pull/79).